# angular infdig error on ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to have an input-select element filled with "panels" from a **JSON-object array**, using ng-options. Inside such a panel, I have several attributes and one of them is the category to which such a panel belongs. It also contains a list of names and a group. Yes, the category and the group are two different things in this case.

When I apply the filter, I get an infdig-error.

Research on the internet tells me that the content of the filter is changing, and that is the cause of the error. When I use ng-repeat the object, the filter does work. But in that way the names associated with a panel are displayed as an array instead of names separated by commas, and also the page isn't updated accordingly.

### The code using ng-options

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectPanel" ng-click="ChangeForm()" ng-options="'(' + panel.group + ') ' + panel.names + ' [' + panel.category + ']' for panel in panels track by panel.id | filter:{category:pageCategory}">
<option value="">Select panel</option>
```

### The code using ng-repeat

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectPanel" ng-click="ChangeForm()">
                        <option value="">Select panel</option>
                        <option ng-repeat="panel in panels | filter:{category:pageCategory}" value="panel.id">{{panel.names}}</option>
                    </select>
```

### JSON-object example

```
{
        "id":"01",
        "category":"RD",
        "group":"A",
        "room": "1.00",
        "names": [
            "Bob",
            "Jamie",
            "Bill"
        ]
    }
```

I want to filter the panels because the page only contains the information of a single category, but the JSON-data contains all the categories. Is there any way to avoid the infdig-error in the ng-options or a way to update the page when using the ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the ng-repeat solution is printing an array object is because you are telling it to print an array object. You need to tell angular to print each name in `panel.names`.

So add another ng-repeat:
`<span ng-repeat="name in panel.names">{{name}},</span>`

Please note that will leave you with a trailing comma.

As for the ng-options solution, not entirely sure what caused the infdig-error, but you do seem to be missing the `as` part of the syntax.